# Determine program path from leafname and PATH environment variable in C++

Tags: c++, qt, boost, path

Today I had the need to implement a task in my C++ program which is easy from the shell, to whit:

```
% which foo
/usr/local/bin/foo
```

Here is a sketch of my solution:

```
QString leafName("foo");

QString resolvedPath;
QString paths(qgetenv("PATH"));
QStringList components = paths.split(':');
QStringList::iterator iter, e_iter = components.end();
for (iter = components.begin(); iter != e_iter; ++iter)
{
   QString aPath(*iter);
   aPath += "/";
   aPath += leafName;

   QFileInfo fInfo(aPath);
   if (fInfo.exists())
   {
      resolvedPath = fInfo.canonicalFilePath();
      break;
   }
}
if (resolvedPath.isEmpty()) {
   resolvedPath = leafName;
}
// inform user of path we intend to execute from
```

I only wrote this code after searching in vain for a canned version in Boost filesystem and Qt, as well as Googling. The Google matches all thought I was asking for the full path of my own running program.

This seems like a reasonable atom of functionality, such that it is silly to write it myself. Does it exist?

Comment: What about `system("which foo");`? Obviously, constructing the string parameter passed to `system` appropriately.

Comment: @IInspectable, a colleague offered that as well. It is a reasonable response, however, I'm hoping also for a direct API ala Boost. Thanks.

Comment: File systems and APIs are orthogonal. It's just way too complex to get all intricacies of even the major systems abstracted behind a common interface. Working with files always tends to be platform specific. Boost gets it wrong, on occasion, Qt gets it wrong more often than it doesn't. I'm afraid, at this point you'll just have to roll your own, one way or another.